# How to set a keymap to run code in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I currently have multiple keymaps to run code, meaning a separate shortcut for Python, Java, C++, C. Is there a possibility to bind the run method for all of them to a single key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need the extension **Code Runner**.

In the description of the extension there is:

> To run code:
> use shortcut `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`N`
> or press `F1` and then select/type `Run Code`,
> or right click the Text Editor and then click `Run Code` in editor context menu
> or click `Run Code` button in editor title menu
> or click `Run Code` button in context menu of file explorer

Hope it helps ;-)

Comment: I even had it already installed... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `editorLangId` to the `where` property

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+alt+f5",
  "command": "run python",
  "when": "editorTextFocus && editorLangId == python"
},
{
  "key": "ctrl+alt+f5",
  "command": "run c++",
  "when": "editorTextFocus && editorLangId == cpp"
}
```